# New Database Column Not Listed Out on Cube's Measure Source List

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssas, cube, bids, olap-cube

I've the task to add 3 new measures and 1 one new calculated measure into an existing SSAS 2005 project. The new measures required a database schema change to add 3 new columns.

Problem: 
When trying to create New Measures I define the "**Usage**" (Sum), "**Source Table**" (xyz table) but the fresh columns are not being listed out on the "**Source Column**" list related to the table. Obviously, I've selected "**Show all columns**" check at the end of the list, but I'm still not seeing the columns.

I have tried the following 2 actions with no expected results:

- Double checked existing Data Source connection string (dsv). It's referencing the correct server/database.All other settings remains unused.
- On Data Source views, opened the existing dsv and validated the table under interest belongs to "Included Objects" list.

I'am under active investigation but if anybody out there has any clue of what could be happening or can provide any advice I will be happy to read and give it a try.

Thanks in advance

Env: 
Windows Server R2 Standard Ed (x64);
SQL Server 2005 9.0 (x64);
SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio

Comment: Are you sure the columns don't contain text values, if so the SUM option is not available.

Comment: @Phicon - Yes, I defined the columns a double and loaded with values. No chance it would contain text values. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad to say after several hours I found the solution myself. Here it is:

- Opened **Data Source View** -> **Add/Remove Objects** -> select the table under interest from the **Included Objects** list -> push it out to **Available Objects** list and click “**Ok**”.
- After that, just inlcuded back the table into the **Available Objects** list, click “**Ok**” and that was all!

I hope this solution save somebody else time looking for the correct solution.

Thanks to all who replied and provided comments on this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go into your Data Source View, right-click on the background, and select "Refresh". Only then will changes of the relational database appear in the Data Source View, which is the base for all references to the relational model from the Analysis Services dimensions and cubes.

Comment: @FrankPI: appreciate your comment but it didn't work. I just needed to update the DSV definition as explained on my response. Thanks for taking the time to reply.